How to efficiently get all transactions of a particular mint address
How to efficiently get all transactions of a particular mint address, Since transfer doesn't reference to mint address, filtering transaction by mint address doesn't include transfer transaction.

Put simply, without going through all transactions and seeing if the mint matches up, you can't! There's no easy way to search in this case
